# require em component do vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, require

boa tarde não consigo usar o require do "axios" no arquivo de component do vue. Como resolver isso?
o arquivo em questão é o home.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');
Vue.component('home-page', {
    template: `
        <div>
           <input type='text' v-model='nome' >{{nome}} 
        </div>
    `,

    data: function () {

        return {
            nome: "teste",
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {

    }
})
```

o erro que aparece é o :

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at home-page-component.js:1"
```

Sem mais, obrigado pela atenção!!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o require só funcionaria no node amigo (Caso não esteja usando uma lib de import), tente usar a sintaxe do es6:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: oi, não deu certo não, o erro informado é "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"